# How to convert lists of years, months, days into list of datetimes?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe of temperature data with column headers of year, month, day, and temperature. The days and months are numbered instead of labeled (i.e. first row = year: 1981, month = 1, day = 1; second row = year: 1981, month = 1, day = 2; etc)

How do I go about converting these individual lists of years, months, and days (specifically the latter two) into datetimes of the format:

first row date = Jan 1, 1981; second row date = Jan 2, 1981; etc

I basically want to condense the three columns of date pieces into one column of dates.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(year, month, day)

# For a dataframe:
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.date(row['year'], row['month'], row['day']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A clunky way of doing it would be to loop through each row. Here I create a dummy pandas dataframe called 'data' with Year, Month, Day, and Temperature. I then create a new column called DateTime and calculate the datetime for each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
data = pd.DataFrame([[2000, 1, 1, 40], [2000, 4, 1, 20], [2000, 7, 1, 5], [2000, 10, 1, 15], [2000, 1, 1, 35], [2000, 4, 1, 25], [2000, 7, 1, 0], [2000, 10, 1, 10]], columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Temperature'])
data['DateTime'] = 0
for ii in range(len(data)):
    data['DateTime'][ii] = dt.datetime(data['Year'][ii], data['Month'][ii], data['Day'][ii])
```

There must be a better way, but until someone posts I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with pandas so I can't address the specific syntax for extracting the year/month/day from your dataframe.

However, once you do have these three pieces of information, it's straightforward to create a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime(year=my_year, month=my_month, day=my_day)
```